# Valuation Property for mean width

Tags: geometric-topology, convex-geometry, geometric-probability

For some polyhedron, $P$, define the mean width function,

$$H(P)=\sum_{e\in E} L_e(\pi - \delta_e)/(4\pi)$$

Where $E$ is the set of all edges of the polyhedron, $L_e$ is the length of edge $e$ and $\delta_e$ is the interior angle where the two faces forming edge $e$ meet (e.g. for a cube the interior angle between two faces is always $\pi/2$). (Note: this may not actually represent the mean width for a concave shape).

My question is, for possibly concave and possibly intersecting polyhedra, $P$ and $Q$, does the following 'valuation property' hold and, if so, where could I find a proof of this:

$H(P\cup Q) = H(P) + H(Q) - H(P \cap Q)$

I did find these questions ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258643/intuition-behind-the-dehn-invariant) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194635/is-mean-width-a-dehn-invariant)) about the "valuation property" but the answers seem to disagree on whether this holds for concave polyhedra!

Also, I feel I should mention I have posted a similar question on Math Overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307681/interpretation-of-this-sum-for-concave-bodies) but in this question I was interested in the interpretation rather than the result.